# THREE.js issues with Scene-in-Scene

Tags: three.js

I've got a nice little mini-app working on fiddle - but failing in my actual webpage, as it gives me the following warning:

```
three js UniformLocation is not from the current active Program
```

First, here's my fiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/tcpwez72/150/

And here's what's happening in my webpage:

1. I've got 20 instances of the same model displayed at random locations on the screen. When I tap on one of them, the "detailsScene" pops-open showing me the enlarged view of that object. **NOTE:** this is slightly different from what you see in the fiddle, where the "detailsScene" is already open and always being displayed at the top right corner. In my app, the "detailsScene" isn't open and doesn't display - *until* you tap on an object. Otherwise, you do not see it.
2. Now here's the problem: as soon as I tap on the object - in the "detailsScene" - and move the mouse, the object disappears! Just totally vanishes from view. 
   I can't tell if the tiny mouse-movements I'm making are actually causing the ***camera*** in that scene to just fly off to a really far away point - making it look like the object disappeared, or if it's really the object itself that's disappearing, but either way, it disappears, and I can't get it to reappear. (I tried all sorts of mouse-movements to make it reappear - nothing works.)
   And this object-disappearing is consistently happening every single time.

Just to be even clearer, this isn't happening on the `mousedown` (or `pointerdown`) event, it's happening when I hold the mouse down, and then start moving it.
In other words, if I hold the mouse down and then release the mouse - without having moved it all, the object stays in the position.  So it's definitely the mouse-*movement* that's causing this issue.

And again, I'm not getting an outright error, I'm just getting the following warning:

```
three js UniformLocation is not from the current active Program
```

Any ideas what might be causing something like this to happen - and how I might go about troubleshooting it?

Comment: Your JSFiddle works fine for me. I can click-drag and the cube orbits as expected.

Comment: @Marquizzo  Right, so like I said, the code works fine in the fiddle, but it does NOT work in my webpage. So I'm trying to understand what sort of things can cause it to fail. Like I don't even know what this warning/error message means. Or what it could be referring to -  you know what I mean? Have you ever come across this error or have any insights into what it might mean?

Comment: No clue what it could be. It's very difficult to fix a bug that doesn't exist. My best suggestion is to `console.log()` all the values in the drag event, you're probably running into a `NaN` or another value that Three.js can't calculate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your project here: https://thrilling-midi-dumpling.glitch.me/ but i keep running into the same error that is happening on the fiddle whenever you click. "can't read userData from undefined" on line 177 in the glitch project. I suggest fixing that error and perhaps the other error will go away. Sorry this isnt a comment I dont have that access yet. Once that is fixed and youre running into the same disappearing behavior I will look at it again!